# Electron with realm. <Encryption not enabled>

Tags: encryption, realm, electron

i made an app with Electron, react, realm.
my OS is windows 10(x64)

and now i meet a problem when i try to use 'encryptionKey ' option.

var realm = new Realm({schema: [CarSchema, PersonSchema], encryptionKey: new Int8Array(64)});

as you can see, i followed Docs.

and my electron app say "Error: Encryption not enabled at Object."

i try to find the reason for 2 days...but still i can't understand.

i use latest electron(ver.1.6.2) and realm(ver.1.2.0)

and i used 'electron-rebuild' to use realm db in Electron.

so, when i check node_modules

node_modules

------|--relam

------------|-- compiled

------------------|-- electron-v1.6_win32_x64_ <--- this is newly added after i use 
electron-rebuild.

------------------|-- node-v48_win32_x64

if i don't use encryptionKey option, my app is working well with no problems to use relam DB.

please give me an answer how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption and Sync aren't supported on Windows.

This isn't mentioned in the Realm React Native docs, but it's in the Realm Xamarin Docs under Limitations: https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#limitations-on-windows-desktop-or-uwp